Render on transparency checkerboard options?
Is there anything that can be done about the grey/dark grey checkerboard background when rendering transparency in Blender 4.2?
I understand the significance that it's a visual cue...(rendering without a background) but can the colours and/or checkerboard size be changed? You know, for people who have problems with photosensitivity.

Sure. It's in the Preferences( F4  ->  P / Ctrl  +  , ), Themes settings, User Interface section under Transparent Checkerboard:


Beautiful! That's gonna save me a few headaches :)
